# Selecting rows without a value for Date/Time columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm running this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [DVD Copy].[Stock No]
FROM [DVD Copy]
WHERE [DVD Copy].[Catalogue No] =[Forms]![New Rental]![Catalogue No]
And [Issue Date] = Null;
```

Which works fine without the null check for Issue Date. I'm trying to select rows without a Date in the Issue Date column. Is Null the wrong kind of value to use for here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember access correctly, you can write:

```
and not isNull([Issue Date])
```

or write:

```
and [issue Date] is not null
```

instead of comparing to Null, because nothing equals null. (It's a weird paradox...)

Answer (score 0):

On the subject of Nulls in Access (and in general) these articles by Access guru Allen Browne are unmatched in explaining things clearly:

- [Nulls: Do I need them?](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-11.html)
- [Common Errors with Null](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-12.html)